# C++ Searching line into txt file

Tags: c++

There are 1000 names in txt file.

```
1   Jacob   Sophia
2   Mason   Emma
3   Ethan   Isabella
4   Noah    Olivia
5   William     Ava
.....
```

The program always says that the name is not among the popular boy/girl names.

After debugging, l realized that "rank" was never increasing. it was always 1 and I thought that program was only checking the first line. I ran the program again and typed Jacob. Result was same.  I cannot see where my mistake is.

```
int main()
{
    bool boyName = false;
    bool girlName = false;
    ifstream ifs;
    int rank;
    string boy_name, girl_name, name;
    ifs.open("babynames2012.txt");

    if (ifs.fail())
        cout << "fail" << endl;
    else
        cout << "success" << endl;


    cout << "Enter a name" << endl;
    cin >> name;


    while (ifs >> rank)
    {
        ifs >> rank >> boy_name >> girl_name;
        if (name == boy_name)
        {
            cout << name << " is ranked " << rank << " among boy names" << endl;
            boyName = true;
        }
        if (name == girl_name)
        {
            cout << name << " is ranked " << rank << " among girl names" << endl;
            girlName = true;
        }

        if (boyName == false)
        {
            cout << name << " is not among the popular boy names" << endl;
        }
        if (girlName == false)
        {
            cout << name << " is not among the popular girl names" << endl;
        }

    }
        ifs.close();
        system("pause");
        return 0;
}
```

Result was always same

```
<name> is not among the popular boy names.
<name> is not among the popular girl names.
```

Comment: You're reading `rank` twice. And your loop exits after one iteration no matter what.

Comment: Should I change while(ifs >> rank) ?

Comment: You should check for EOF (end of file) ex: `while (!ifs.eof())`

Comment: I have tried it. I could only get good output when I typed Jacob. Jacob is the #1 and output was 1 Jacob. But when I typed Mason(2#) or any name, l got <name> is not among the popular boy names.

Answer (score 0):

Closing `ifs` in the middle of the loop isn't a good idea...

Comment: ouch. They are not supposed to be there. 
fixed the code